# Database Connection via WebLogic

Tags: java, mysql, weblogic, weblogic12c

So I have a MySQL database, and I have a datasource on a local instance of WebLogic which is connected to that database. I am trying to write some client code which will simply connect and query. I am having issues with obtaining a connection from the datasource. Here's my code thus far. I am running WebLogic 12c.

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class ConnectionTest {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        ConnectionTest tCon = new ConnectionTest();
        tCon.TestConnection();

    }

    public void TestConnection() {
        Context ctx = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            Hashtable<String, String> props = new Hashtable<String, String>();

            props.put("java.naming.factory.initial",
                    "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
            props.put("java.naming.provider.url", "t3://localhost:7001");
            props.put("java.naming.security.principal", "weblogic");
            props.put("java.naming.security.credentials", "welcome1");
            ctx = new InitialContext(props);
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("RegexDB");
            System.out.println(ds);
            DAO dao = new DAO();
            conn = ds.getConnection();
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute("select * from regular_ex");
            rs = stmt.getResultSet();
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> results = dao
                    .resultSetToArrayList(rs);
            dao.printArrayList(results);
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (stmt != null)
                    stmt.close();
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This fails at `ds.getConnection()` with the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnv cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable
    at weblogic.iiop.IIOPOutputStream.writeObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:2285)
    at weblogic.utils.io.ObjectStreamClass.writeFields(ObjectStreamClass.java:414)
    at weblogic.corba.utils.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueData(ValueHandlerImpl.java:235)
    at weblogic.corba.utils.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueData(ValueHandlerImpl.java:225)
    at weblogic.corba.utils.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:182)
    at weblogic.iiop.IIOPOutputStream.write_value(IIOPOutputStream.java:1983)
    at weblogic.iiop.IIOPOutputStream.write_value(IIOPOutputStream.java:2021)
    at weblogic.iiop.IIOPOutputStream.writeObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:2285)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:695)
    at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableServerRef.invoke(ClusterableServerRef.java:230)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:520)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:516)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

I have wlclient.jar, wlsafclient.jar, and weblogic.jar in my buildpath. I have tried all sorts of combinations of adding/removing these jars, but I still get the same error regardless of what I do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: remove all jars and just use weblogic.jar ensure that you are taking jar from <weblogic_installation_directory>\server\lib directory

Comment: I have already tried that. These jars are from my server installation. If I only use the weblogic.jar, I get the following exception:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/security/subject/AbstractSubject

Comment: I have to try with weblogic 12c, I just ran the same code with Weblogic 10 and it worked correctly just with weblogic.jar

Comment: According to this forum post: https://kr.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=940386, you need to build and use this jar: wlfullclient.jar. This explains how to build it: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13717/jarbuilder.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After doing some research, I am deleting my old answer and starting over.

There is a large table of client types in the [Oracle Doc for WebLogic Standalone Clients](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13717/basics.htm#BEIFHGEC). For each type of client, listed, the table shows the required jar files. For certain types of clients, you need to build an additional jar (wlfullclient.jar) and include that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you doing this in a JSP? I have to set the property values for the initial context in mine since it is just a client java application.

Comment: Yes, there was a comment from mprabhat here a minute ago that explained that my code would only work when run within the Web App. So that explains why this won't work for you.

Comment: Completely rewrote my answer after researching the issue a bit.

Comment: BINGO! Works like a charm now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I created the wlfullclient.jar, and I removed all other jars. I recompiled, and it worked. There must have been a missing class that was included when I built the wlfullclient.jar.

Comment: wlfullclient.jar and jarbuilder are deprecated starting from the WebLogic 12.1.3 release+equivalent stand-alone clients instead
Please use one of the equivalent stand-alone clients instead.  Consult Oracle WebLogic public Any idea what exactly is the alternate for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have also face this problem and I tried to add "wlfullclient.jar" to my directory to fix it out but I didn't find this jar file in weblogic installation folder.

But at the last I have set all required jar files form weblogic by using setDomainEnv.cmd and it works fine. Here we don't have to care about which jar files required or not it'll simply set classpath for all required jar file for your program.

I am using Weblogic 11g.

Comment: You have to build it, see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e13717/jarbuilder.htm#SACLT239

Answer (score 0):

In Weblogic 12c, copy the weblogic.jar file to some other directory. Rename the file to weblogic-classes.jar and then build the jar file using wljarbuilder.

Add the newly created wlfullclient.jar file to your Class Path in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Build wlfullclient.jar and add just this jar to the build path.
It solved the problem for me.
By the way weblogic.jar from Weblogic 12 is missing some classes as compared to weblogic.jar from Weblogic 10.3